# What is the difference between "Memory" in Task Manager and "Installed Memory (RAM)" in System Settings?

Tags: memory, task-manager

In Task Manager, it says 80% (ish) of my memory is being used, which is about 2500 MB (ish). But in Control Panel / System Settings, it says only 0.16 GB of RAM have been used. I'm not sure what "Memory" in Task Manager refers to if not RAM, and why are these numbers different?

[image]

.

[image]

Comment: System memory is Usable memory, not memory in use. some hardware in the system has reserved the 0.16 which is only used by that device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is stated under "System" is the memory the operating system is able to use, not what is currently used up. The memory above that is how much it is currently using. SO your device (at that time) was using 82% of your 7.84 GB